# Google Glass bone conduction transducer as input device?

Tags: google-glass

Does Google Glass's bone conduction transducer also work as an input device, and if so, how can one access its readings?

EDIT: Let me clarify why I ask.

According to [Catwig's tear-down](http://www.catwig.com/google-glass-teardown/) "it appears to double as a tactile switch". It's hard to tell from the pictures, so I was wondering how sensitive the switch is, and whether or not it could be used to detect vibrations in the skull. If this is the case, it could be used to enhance voice command accuracy by identifying which sounds are originating from the wearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr**: The speaker on Glass is not a button. Do not press it.

The speaker may appear to double as a tactile switch, but it does not. Depressing it like a button makes a clicking sound, but it does not generate a signal and it's not designed to be pressed like a button.